# .addClass() not functioning properly

Tags: jquery, meteor

In one one of my spacebar calls `currentCategory`, I call `addClass(disabled-link)`, which changes the color of the current category text. This works normally when I am clicking on categories on this page, which essentially just reroutes back to the same page, listing items for the clicked on category. However, when I first arrive at this page from another page, the current category text is not changed properly.

Here is my Template.*template_name*.helper call for this:

```
currentCategory: function(category) {
    check(category, String);
    //console.log(this);
    if(String(this) == Session.get('category')){
        console.log('matching category ' + category);
        $("#" + category).addClass('disabled-link');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is the html that calls this function:

```
<div class="filter-list" id="category-filter">
    <h3>Filter by:</h3>
        {{#each category}}
            <div class="filter-element" id={{this}}>
            {{#if currentCategory this}}

                    <div class="accompany-icon">

                    </div>
                    {{this}}

                {{else}}
                    <a class="filter-link" href="{{pathFor 'produceListFilter' _filter=this}}">
                        <div class="accompany-icon">

                        </div>
                        {{this}}
                    </a>
            {{/if}}
            </div>
        {{/each}}


</div>
```

As seen above, I rely on a Session variable, but I can confirm that every time, the Session variable is set properly and does run the `.addClass` function, but the UI changes are not there. In case this helps, this is my css:

```
.disabled-link {
    color: #666666;
}
```

Is there something special about rendering that prevents me from editing the DOM until it fully renders or something? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Make sure `#CATEGORYVARIABLE` exists before the `.addClass()` function is ran!

Comment: Adding to James comment, you should try debugging techniques like console logging and alerting things and see if they are indeed correct

Comment: Like I said above, I did ( `console.log('matching category ' + category);`). I even hard-coded the command so it wouldn't depend on the category variable. So it definitely is not that issue.

Comment: Try giving `!important` to color property!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty high percentage of questions about meteor come down to things not being rendered in time for the javascript that is supposed to run on it.  Try putting this into the `Template.template_name.onRendered`.
I would also put it in the parent template, and run it in a tracker.afterFlush so it isn't running every time the sub-template runs.

```
Template.template_name.onRendered(function(){
  if (!this.rendered){ //run only on first render
    tracker.afterFlush(highlightCategory);
  }
});

function highlightCategory(){
  Session.get('category');
  $("#" + category).addClass('disabled-link');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it perfectly!